# How do I locate my doorbell wire?

Tags: electrical, doorbell

**I would like to install a wired doorbell, but I don't know how to find the wires to hook up the doorbell.**

I live in a relatively recently constructed townhouse, built in 2016. The seller indicated that it has wiring in place for a wired doorbell, though he never installed one.

I believe I've found the doorbell transformer in the utility closet, and my multimeter says it's putting out 22VAC:

[image: a doorbell transformer mounted to the wall of a utility closet]

Here is what the bell looks like with the cover removed. The red wires also measure 22VAC. I found it like this, with one of the red wires disconnected:

[image: a doorbell bell housing with the cover removed]

If I touch the loose red wire to either the front or rear terminals, it sets off the bell. This indicates to me that there's a closed loop where I'd expect the doorbell to go.

Here is what it looks like out front where one would expect the doorbell to be:

[image: exterior wall next to a door, where a doorbell would be found]

I actually pried off one of the siding panels to see if I could see anything, but it's just house wrap behind that one panel. I didn't try looking behind other panels or the doorframe since I didn't want to pull parts off the house without some educated guess as to where to start.

Comment: Is the inside wall beside the door easy to remove/repair(drywall easy, tile hard)?  Add pictures of inside to your question.  Wires inside the wall hopefully be at/near common door bell height.

Comment: @crip659 It's drywall, so it'd be fairly easy to remove. However, it's also textured, which I'm guessing is gonna make it a pain to cover up the outline where I cut out the piece of drywall. But... I do have a light switch right behind where the doorbell would be, so I can try pulling that box out to search for the wires.

Comment: Just make sure the power is off to that switch/light and it will give a small decent hole to look in, might need to pull the box out.  Take pictures of how the wires are connected, so connecting back up is easy and not a puzzle.

Comment: The "loose red wire" should be coming from the doorbell button, and only be "hot" when someone is pressing on the button.  You need to install a doorbell button and a pair of wires from the button to the doorbell.

Comment: @HotLicks I suspect that the unconnected red wire at the chime and its white partner *are* the preinstalled pair of wires from the chime box to the doorbell button area, and that the builder just connected the red and white wires to each other at the unlocated doorbell end for a function check in the absence of an actual button.  Once the OP finds those wire ends, he should just connect them to his doorbell button, connect the loose red wire at the chime to either the left or right ringer, and it all should work.

Comment: Re: "The red wires also measure 22VAC. " What exactly were you measuring? I suspect one of the red wires in the chime is hot and the other neutral; if both were hot or both neutral, the chime should not ring when you attach the 2nd red wire.

Comment: I pulled the electrical box and the doorbell cable was nowhere to be found in the area. I might have to try a wire tracer.

Answer (score 2):

See if you can rent a wire tracer. This tool has two parts: A signal generator and a probe.

1. Disconnect power to the transformer.
2. Disconnect the red wire from the "Trans" terminal on the chimes, and connect it to the loose red wire.
3. Disconnect the door bell wires from the transformer, and connect them to the signal generator.
4. Scan the area around the door with the probe.

There are electronic wall scanners or stud findersthat can detect wire. But, I don't know enough about them. If you are thinking of using one, ask these questions:

- Can it detect un-energized wires inside the wall?
- Can it detect low-voltage energized wires inside the wall?
- How deep inside the wall can it detect wires?

Comment: I'm not yet allowed to comment, except on my own answers. Providing an answer is the only way I can participate in this discussion.

Comment: I agree: The end of the white wire and the end of the red wire meant to be wired to the switch are connected together somewhere.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a basement or an attic in which the wires are visible?

Comment: Instead of starting the scan by the front door, try following the wires by starting the scan at the chimes.

Comment: I'll see if I can find a wire tracer, thanks for the suggestion!